# Django form with list of foreign key fields

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the below models for which I'm trying to create a form for:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   publish_date = models.TimeField()

class LetterRecipients(models.Model):
   letter = models.ForeignKey(Letter)
   recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   recipient_rating = models.IntegerField()
   has_responded = models.BooleanField()
```

I'd like a single form that allows the user to enter a title and publish_date for the letter, and in the same form enter multiple recipients by name and rating.

Can anyone help with creating the form model for this? I can't figure out how to have django generate this form using `{{ form.as_p }}`. I think I'll have to use jQuery to create the additional recipient rows on the HTML page, but how would I get django to parse those into the model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Ark

Answer (score 7):

Ark, you can use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) in Django form. Here are some roughly example. I create "posts" apps just for quick testing :

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django_test.posts.models import Letter, LetterRecipients


class LetterForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    publish_date = forms.TimeField()
    recepient = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                        queryset=LetterRecipients.objects.all()
                                        )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Letter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publish_date = models.TimeField()


class LetterRecipients(models.Model):
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Letter)
    recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recipient_rating = models.IntegerField()
    has_responded = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.recipient_name
```

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django_test.posts.forms import LetterForm
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    form = LetterForm()
    data = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', data)
```

index.html

```
{% load url from future %}

{{ form.as_p }}
```