# Add UserAdmin reverse ForeignKey management in Django

Tags: python, django

I am encountering a problem when I try to add reverse ForeignKey field to UserAdmin:

My model is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    layout = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    todo_set = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

So there's an test_set attribute in User model. And now I want to manage this m2m relation in User change view, so there must be an chosen field about test_set.

I tried:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

custom_fieldsets = list(UserAdmin.fieldsets)
custom_fieldsets.append((None, {'fields': ('test_set', )}))

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = custom_fieldsets

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

But Django raises an error:

```
'CustomUserAdmin.fieldsets[4][1]['fields']' refers to field 'test_set' that is missing from the form.
```

How should I do it? THX!

Comment: The field name is `todo_set`not `test_set`

Comment: Please check my code, I want to display attribute on User model, not Test model, so reverse ForienKey on User model is test_set.

Comment: Sorry i should have focused more

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you could use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField).  Check out this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672811/django-form-with-list-of-foreign-key-fields).