# Can I input any character value to form which is defined as ForeignkeyField?

Tags: django

First, This is my first question in stack overflow, please bear with me.

Using Django. I want to let users to input a character value to form defined as Foreignkey field (in this case, it's category form).

#### models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Listing(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="category_name")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.title}: {self.description}: {self.starting_bid}: {self.image}: {self.category}"
```

#### forms.py

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ["title", "description", "starting_bid", "image", "category"]
```

#### views.py

```
def create_listing_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listings'))
    else:
        form = ListingForm()
    return render(request, 'auctions/create.html', {'form': form})
```

#### create.html

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>create</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Create</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

[this image is present condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq0kt.png)

I tried to do this myself, but I couldn't do as I want. So far I compromising that letting user input a value to category form as dropdown value like uploaded image(not inputting a character value).

I appreciate giving me a solution for this, also telling me which is best idea to let users input a character value whatever users want to input to category form or only to prompt users to input **dropdown value** to category form like now.

Comment: I don't really understand the question? FK fields store the ID of the related record. Can you explain the use case?

Comment: I think OP wants to create the `Category` with its `Category.name` via the `ListingForm`. To achieve this is a bit tricky to do, because by default, if you want to create relations in django, those **related objects have to be created before**. Another phrasing: When you create `Listing` you can only relate it to already existing `Category`s. Please confirm that you are trying to create a `Listing` **and** its future related `Category` (which is not already in db) in one go.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you show a mockup of what you want the UI to look like? Even if you just draw a picture in MS Paint, that would help us understand a lot more.

Comment: Thanks for you two comments. I just edited my question to fixed my mistake in my question.
Could you see my question again?  
@Tarquinius
As you said, I want to create the Category with its Category.name via the ListingForm.

I also want to know whether it's adequate way to let users to input the value category form as dropdown value.
To let users input the value category form as dropdown value is done so far like image in my original question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have a dropdown on the ListingForm that shows the list of category names for the user to choose from, is that right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django form with list of foreign key fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672811/django-form-with-list-of-foreign-key-fields)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
It's no problem to implement a dropdown feature on the ListingForm.  
Is there a way to let users input a character value users want to input on **category form** on the ListingForm?

Comment: What do you mean by "category form on the ListingForm"? Where is this in your code? What character value do you want to allow the user to input? What does this character stand for? What field is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's better to say can we use multiple models in a form :
yes there's a way you can make different form classes and then pass them by the view to the template and mention both forms in your template.By this approach users can input there own categories in `listingform` like you wanted just you should change your code like this :

## forms.py :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Listing
from .models import Category


class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ["title", "description", "starting_bid", "category"]


class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ["name"]
```

## views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ListingForm
from .forms import CategoryForm
# Create your views here.


def create_listing_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_l = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_c = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form_l.is_valid() and form_c.is_valid():
            form_l.save()
            form_c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        listing_form = ListingForm()
        category_form = CategoryForm()
    return render(request, 'app/create.html', {
        "listing_form": listing_form,
        "category_form": category_form,
    })
```

## create.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>create</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ listing_form }}
        {{ category_form }}
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Create</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  There is such nice idea to put mutiple form(ListingForm, CategoryForm) into a view(create_listing_view).  
However, After run this code, I realized a thing posting data to multiple models in a template are not linked by one manupulation.  
So, I've reached that It's best way I set **dropdown category form** only using listing_form and I should allow users to create **category names** on another page.  
I'm so appreciate for your answer and suggestion to import classes(Listing, Category) individually on forms.py.

Comment: @kousuke yeah it's better to let them do that on another page like an admin panel, if answer was helpful please vote up and approve it

Comment: As I said already in the comments: related objects have to be created before they can be assigned to another model. This code does not answer the question because it does not link created objects.

Comment: @Tarquinius my answer is based on my own knowledge and the owner of the question approved my answer, In your comment you said you didn't even understand the question so don't make other users confused by baseless votes.